# Don't know if fsck failed or not

Tags: output, fsck, sd-card

I just ran fsck on my newly bought SD card for my Raspberry Pi and it shows the following output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
/dev/mmcblk0p1: 75 files, 2539/7673 clusters
```

It doesn't say clean anywhere and exists with error code 1333 (if I do echo $! after running fsck). Is this bad or not? I don't know, sorry.

Comment: There are no warnings or errors in what you posted. Why did you run fsck and what makes you think it failed?

Comment: The strange error code and that it says /dev/mmcblk0p1: 75 files, 2539/7673 clusters with no clean in it (otherwise it always says clean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return status is in `$?`.

`$!` holds the PID of the last background process.